# Python won't start after updating Seaborn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda last year, and Jupyter notebook and Spyder work fine. I updated seaborn this morning, (pip install --upgrade seaborn==0.11.1 --user). Then Anaconda, Jupyter notebook and Spyder cann't start.

The error shows when I tried to start Jupyter notebook :
[image]

The following error shows when I tried to update some packages:
[image]

Both error end with AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Please help! Any advices would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do :

First activate your conda env ( conda activate XXXX)

Then list the successive revisions for your conda env, using:

```
conda list -r
```

You should be able to see all the successive installation you made.
Then just rollback to the previous revision of that time you did update seaborn, for example if it's revision 8:

```
conda install --revision 8
```

Comment: Also if you are using conda/miniconda, use conda to install package instead of pip

Comment: can you try and make me a feedback ? dont forget to add specific channel in conda install, if, for example, you have installed packages from conda-forge

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am using company laptop. Due to some wired setting, pip install is the only option. Following your suggestion, I tried pip list, and it showed the same error, ending with:  AttributeError:'_NamespacePath' object has no attribute sort.

Comment: I uninstalled the anaconda, then reinstalled it again. However, the problem remains.